# Hi, how would I go about animating this jquery slider to a specific value on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I have this basic jquery slider in a form and I'd like to have it animate to a specific value on page load but can't seem to make it happen:

[my codepen][1]

[1]: http://codepen.io/lami0007/pen/MyEoed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animating slider handle when altering the jQuery UI slider value option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123067/animating-slider-handle-when-altering-the-jquery-ui-slider-value-option)

Answer (score 0):

If that specific value is always going to be the same, just set it in your jquery.
On the 4th line of your JS file, there is a value called "value". Changing that number will cause it to load in as that value.

If the value will change depending on the situation, you should make an OnLoad event that sets that value.

Comment: I tried that, but I want it to animate into that position on load.
I added the animate: true command already but it's still not doing it.